# Why am I getting this odd log4j Exception?

Tags: java, exception, log4j

I've got a code base that has been working for months, today i deployed an update to a customer site and I've started getting the following Exception:

> Exception in thread "Thread-75"
>   Exception in thread "Thread-66"
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.log4j.spi.LocationInfo.(LocationInfo.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getLocationInformation(LoggingEvent.java:247)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternParser$LocationPatternConverter.convert(PatternParser.java:483)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.PatternConverter.format(PatternConverter.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout.format(PatternLayout.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
>     at
>   org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)

The code that initiated this is a log.debug() statement, I've got no idea why this is happening. Also it works fine on my machine, but fails on the customer site.

Here is an anonymized version of the log configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Threshold" value="ERROR"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <!-- Print the date in ISO 8601 format -->
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS}][line:%3L] [%5p] [%F %M()] - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 
  <appender name="x_trace" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/logs/x_trace.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS}][line:%3L]%5p [%t] ( %F %M()) - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender>  
  <appender name="y_trace" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/logs/y_trace.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS}][line:%3L]%5p [%t] ( %F %M()) - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender>  
  <appender name="application" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/logs/application.log"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB" />
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20" />
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SS}][line:%3L]%5p [%t] ( %F %M()) - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 
  <!-- failureLogger Logs SQL queries that were not written to the database so they can be rolled in -->
  <appender name="failureLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender"> 
    <param name="File" value="C:/apache-tomcat-5.5.17/logs/failures.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="Threshold" value="ALL"/>
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 
  <logger name="nanoxml" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>   
  </logger>   
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>   
  </logger>   
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.applicationContainer" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>   
  </logger> 
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.addressbook.AddressBook" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger>   
   <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.component1.Component1" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger>   
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.component2.Component2" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger>  
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.web.filters" additivity="false">
    <level value="error"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger>  
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.web" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger>  
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.util.SettingsHandler" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger> 
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.application.util" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger> 
  <logger name="org.apache.axis.enterprise" additivity="false">
    <level value="FATAL"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>
  </logger>  
  <logger name="com.vendor.api1" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="x_trace"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="com.vendor.api2" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="y_trace"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="com.vendor.lib1" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="y_trace"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="ch.ecma" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="y_trace"/>
  </logger>
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.vendor.middlewareAPI" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>   
  </logger>
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.vendor2.workStationAPI" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>   
  </logger>   
  <logger name="uk.co.companyName.CustomerLib1" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>  
    <appender-ref ref="application"/>   
  </logger>   
  <logger name="FaileStatementLogger" additivity="false">
    <level value="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="failureLogger"/>
  </logger>
  <root>  
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="stdout" /> -->
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Hi, as it is linked to appenders' definition, you may want to provide your log4j configuration.

Comment: Added configuration, I had to remove any references company/product names.

Comment: Hope you've not run out of space on the machine/box where this code is deployed.

Comment: Nope drive has 124 Gigs of space left.

Comment: What version of log4j are you using? Then look at the source, eg: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_15/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.java?revision=929374&view=markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the [code for 1.2.15](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/logging/log4j/tags/v1_2_15/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/spi/LocationInfo.java?revision=572985&view=markup), it appears that a `private static StringWriter` is `null`, which may indicate lack of available memory. Not 100% sure what scenarios there are that would allow a class to end up in that sort of condition.

In particular, the code looks like this

```
56    private static StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
57    private static PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

112    synchronized(sw) {
113        t.printStackTrace(pw);
114        s = sw.toString();
115        sw.getBuffer().setLength(0);
116    }
```

You're getting an NPE for the synchronized call, which is on the static member.

Comment: While I can see where it's going wrong, can someone comment on how this scenario can occur? I'm pondering the memory possibility, or maybe some concurrency issue.

Comment: I checked and the memory usage on the machine is 94% so this might be the issue... Although I can't see anything using up the memory :S so it could be something much worse wrong with the box.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check in your consumer box classpath what is the log4j version you have and what is there in your lib?
Give a try by not providing the log4j jar in the lib folder.